# Pandas Categorical equality test

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.24.2 and am unable to perform simple equality tests for [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) instances. For example, with this code:

```
d = DataFrame({"x" : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
d["y"] = pd.cut(d["x"], bins=3)
```

The contents of `d` are now:

```
    x   y
0   1   (0.997, 2.0]
1   2   (0.997, 2.0]
2   3   (2.0, 3.0]
3   4   (3.0, 4.0]
```

However, I cannot test `y` for equality to string values, e.g.:

```
d["y"] == '(3.0, 4.0]'
```

Produces:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: y, dtype: bool
```

I get that the underlying type of `y` is `Categorical`, due to the output of [`cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). However I cannot find any special methods for equality in the `Categorical`; moreover, the doc even states that "Equality comparisons work with . . . scalars." What am I missing in my approach?

Comment: the y column is of type `pd.Interval`.

So comparision `d["y"] == pd.Interval(0.997, 2.0, closed='right')` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is interval so pass to `pd.Interval`

```
d.y==pd.Interval(3,4)
Out[255]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: y, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could cast as 'string' datatype:

```
d["y"].astype(str) == "(3.0, 4.0]"
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: y, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This definitely works - and it was a tough choice between this answer and the other. In many ways this seems more intuitive; it's interesting that to make it work, you actually have to exit the `Categorical` type altogether. There are lots of places in the pandas API where I notice things like that (indexes, etc.) Thanks again for help!